Unable to Receive Test Request from Facebook Webhook URL - Registration Successful
I have successfully registered my Facebook Webhook URL, but I’m unable to receive the test request from the app dashboard.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:

I’ve registered my webhook URL in the Facebook App Dashboard.
I’ve selected the required webhook fields and subscribed to the events.
The URL is live and accessible via HTTP, and I have validated it with a 200 OK response.
I have set up the necessary code to handle the incoming POST request from Facebook on my server.

When I try to test the webhook via the Facebook App Dashboard, the test request doesn’t appear to reach my server.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Did you trird to test it on webhook.site or try to test it locally with proxy like ngrok?

"the test request doesn’t appear to reach my server" - what is that conclusion based on? Have you first of all checked your web server access log?
